Tableau Dashboard - Displaying view as a filter
I have a tabular report with seven attributes in total.
Account,r1,r2,r3, and r4 are in row shelf and Month in columns shelf with Amount as a measure.
Image1 shows the current view for month 1.
While creating dashboard, I want to display same view from image 1 for different months.
r1,r2,r3 are calculated field for fixed Account and month. R4 is calculated field for count of Y in r1,r2,r3. For different months, I want to see if there is a change in r4 for a given account.
Calculated fields are done, need help in creating a view as shown in Image2.
Image1
Image2
